# How check if exists other process (beyond my) running inside a new desktop created by CreateDesktop() function?

Tags: delphi

I have a application that is executed (via [`CreateProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa)) inside a new desktop created by [`CreateDesktop()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createdesktopa). Then i want know if exists some specific function (or other way) where is possible know if exists some other process (except my) running inside this new desktop when for example i execute a any other software to this new desktop, is possible detect your presence?

Thank you in advance by any suggestion/solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A process is not tied to a specific desktop.  Individual threads are.  A process can have multiple threads running in different desktops at the same time.

For UI apps, you can use [`EnumDesktopWindows()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdesktopwindows) to find all of the windows that are running in your desktop, using [`GetWindowThreadProcessId()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid) and [`GetCurrentProcessId()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentprocessid) to check whether they belong to your process.

For non-UI apps, however, you would have to enumerate all running threads on the system, such as with [`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-createtoolhelp32snapshot), using [`GetThreadDesktop()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getthreaddesktop) to see which ones belong to your desktop, and of those then using [`GetProcessIdOfThread()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getprocessidofthread) and [`GetCurrentProcessId()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getcurrentprocessid) to check whether they belong to your process.